# Como poderia deixar as células de uma tabela dinâmica sem elas desalinharem na tabela em um cabeçalho fixo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tem uma tabela que pode apresentar dados com menos ou mais colunas,esta regra é definida pelas regras que vêm da API, ou seja, ela poderá ter 10 colunas ou 6 colunas, ou 5 etc...

A ideia do que é preciso ser feito, é fixar essa primeira linha dos títulos e fazer com que ela acompanhe a tabela ao rolar a barra do scroll da tela, fixando ela no cabeçalho, isso já acontece através desse script, ele aciona a variável **isFixedTable**, e exibe um outro elemento escondido que á basicamente uma tabela apenas com os dados do **thead** :

```
let lastKnownScrollPosition=0, isFixedTable=false, el;

window.onload = () {
  el = document.querySelector('.top-table');
}

function showHeaderTable(e) {
          
   lastKnownScrollPosition = document.body.scrollTop;
   isFixedTable=false;
   const topPositon = 393; //momento que começa a aparecer o header fixo
   if (lastKnownScrollPosition >= topPositon && window.innerWidth >  880) {
       isFixedTable=true;
   } 
    if(isFixedTable) {
     toggleEventAddRemove(el, 'add')
    } else {
       toggleEventAddRemove(el, 'remove')
    }
}

document.body.onscroll = (event) => {
  showHeaderTable(event)
}

function toggleEventAddRemove(el, action) {
      if(el.classList.contains('hidden') && !el.classList.contains('fix') && action == 'add') {
         el.classList.add('fix');
         el.classList.remove('hidden');
      } else if(el.classList.contains('fix') && !el.classList.contains('hidden') && action == 'remove') {
         el.classList.remove('fix');
         el.classList.add('hidden');
      } else {
         el.classList.remove('fix');
         el.classList.add('hidden');
      }
}
```

Hoje essa tabela, tem as medidas do "**thead rt th**" em porcentagem, exemplo:
**CSS:**

```
table,
table thead tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 6px;
}
.fix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 5;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
table thead tr th.padrao {
   width: 10%;
}
table thead tr th.mediano {
   width: 20%;
}
table thead tr th.maior {
   width: 30%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="responsive-table">
    <table class="top-table hidden">
    <thead>
    <tr>
       <th class="maior">Dados X</th>
       <th class="mendiano">Dados Y</th>
       <th class="padrao">Dados Z</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
   </table>
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
       <th class="maior">Dados X</th>
       <th class="mendiano">Dados Y</th>
       <th class="padrao">Dados Z</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>dado 1.1</td><td>dado 2.1</td><td>dado 3.1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>dado 1.2</td><td>dado 2.2</td><td>dado 3.2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>dado 1.3</td><td>dado 2.3</td><td>dado 3.3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>dado 1.4</td><td>dado 2.4</td><td>dado 3.4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>dado 1.5</td><td>dado 2.5</td><td>dado 3.5</td></tr>
      <tr><td>dado 1.6</td><td>dado 2.6</td><td>dado 3.6</td></tr>
      <tr><td>dado 1.7</td><td>dado 2.7</td><td>dado 3.7</td></tr>
      <tr><td>dado 1.8</td><td>dado 2.8</td><td>dado 3.8</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[Fiddle de exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/twyj5dpe/1/)

Essa tabela é responsiva, ou seja, ela pode ter um scroll na largura, caso o número de colunas ultrapasse o tamanho da tela no navegador. A classe do boostrap responsável por fazer isso: **.responsive-table**

Para esse caso, eu capturei o event de scrolling e setei scrollLeft do cabeçalho, pegando o scrollLeft da tabela responsiva, mas isso não vem ao caso agora, o mais importante é conseguir alinhar as colunas do cabeçalho fixo com o cabeçalho da tabela na página.

Esse print é um exemplo do problema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse outro print, tenho um exemplo onde a mesma tabela,trás mais colunas, veja que nesse caso, ficou relativamente alinhada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está acontecendo é que a porcentagem muda descabidamente na largura entre as colunas. É o mesmo CSS, padding e border das tabelas. A única diferença é que a tabela do cabeçalho não possui o `<tbody>` com os conteúdos, esses é que estão impactando na estrutura do `<thead>` da tabela inferior.

Comment: Acontece o desalinhamento quando o conteúdo da tag td ultrapassa o tamanho definido na tag th do cabeçalho. Você pode definir para o as tags `<th>` e `<td>` os atributos css `max-width` e `width` com o mesmo valor, em ambas as tabelas, mesmo que em porcentagem, deve resolver o problema.

Comment: Coloquei "max-width: 200px; width: 200px;" na th e na td da primeira coluna e mesmo assim, a th está com 279px, ou seja o max-width não funcionou...

Comment: padding-left, padding-right, border-left e border-right também precisam ter o mesmo tamanho definidos para th e td em ambas as tabelas.

Comment: Além disso, fica a questão de que a tabela precisa preencher toda a tela em porcentagem 100%, se eu fixar uma largura, eu perco essa dimensão.

Answer (score 0):

Esse é o maior problema das tabelas, quando eu passei um tempo desenvolvendo e-mails acabei aprendendo que elas são extremamente limitantes e os códigos CSS que você aplica a uma `table` não se comporta como seria em uma `div` ou não surte efeito nenhum.

A unica solução que eu tenho pra você é fazer como é feito em e-mail e nas epocas antes do movimento *"tabless"*, `table` dentro de `table`.

Fazendo isso você consegue deixar as tabelas filhas com **largura de 100%** e o tamanho delas vão ser o mesmo todas as vezes.

Seu exemplo alterado:

```js
 let lastKnownScrollPosition=0, isFixedTable=false, el, tab;

    window.onload = () => {
      el = document.querySelector('.top-table');
      tab = document.getElementById('table');

    }
    
    function showHeaderTable(e) {
              
       lastKnownScrollPosition =  window.scrollY;
       //console.log(lastKnownScrollPosition)
       isFixedTable=false;
       const topPositon = 1; //momento que começa a aparecer o header fixo
       if (lastKnownScrollPosition >= topPositon && window.innerWidth >  880) {
           isFixedTable=true;
       } 
       
          waitForFinalEvent(() => {
              fixedElement(isFixedTable);
            }, 100,"some unique string");
    }
    
    function fixedElement(isFixedTable) {
       if(isFixedTable) {
          el.style.width = tab.clientWidth+'px';
           toggleEventAddRemove(el, 'add');
        } else {
           toggleEventAddRemove(el, 'remove');
        }
    }
    
    document.body.onscroll = (event) => {
   
        showHeaderTable(event)
    }

    function toggleEventAddRemove(el, action) {
          if(el.classList.contains('hidden') && !el.classList.contains('fix') && action == 'add') {
             el.classList.add('fix');
             el.classList.remove('hidden');
          } else if(el.classList.contains('fix') && !el.classList.contains('hidden') && action == 'remove') {
             el.classList.remove('fix');
             el.classList.add('hidden');
          } else {
             el.classList.remove('fix');
             el.classList.add('hidden');
          }
    }
    
   let waitForFinalEvent = (() => {
        var timers = {};
        return  (callback, ms, uniqueId) => {
          if (!uniqueId) {
            uniqueId = "Don't call this twice without a uniqueId";;
          }
          if (timers[uniqueId]) {
            clearTimeout (timers[uniqueId]);
          }
          timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    })();
```

```css
table,
table thead tr th,
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 6px;
}
table.extra-large {
  width: 1000px;
}
table thead tr th.padrao {
width: 10%;
}
table thead tr th.mediano {
width: 20%;
}
table thead tr th.maior {
width: 30%;
}

.responsive-table {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.fix {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width:100%;
        background: white;
        z-index: 5;
        margin: 0 8px;
        max-width: 1000px;
}

    .hidden {
       display: none;
    }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="responsive-table">
    <table width="100%" class="top-table hidden">
      <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="maior">Dados X</th>
         <th class="mendiano">Dados Y</th>
         <th class="padrao">Dados Z</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" id="table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="maior">Dados X</th>
         <th class="mendiano">Dados Y</th>
         <th class="padrao">Dados Z</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>dado 1.1</td><td>dado 2.1</td><td>dado 3.1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>dado 1.2</td><td>dado 2.2</td><td>dado 3.2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>dado 1.3</td><td>dado 2.3</td><td>dado 3.3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>dado 1.4</td><td>dado 2.4</td><td>dado 3.4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>dado 1.5</td><td>dado 2.5</td><td>dado 3.5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>dado 1.6</td><td>dado 2.6</td><td>dado 3.6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>dado 1.7</td><td>dado 2.7</td><td>dado 3.7</td></tr>
        <tr><td>dado 1.8</td><td>dado 2.8</td><td>dado 3.8</td></tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>

</div>
<br><br>
<table width="100%" class="extra-large">
<thead>
<tr>
   <th class="maior">Dados X</th>
   <th class="mendiano">Dados Y</th>
   <th class="padrao">Dados Z</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>dado 1.1</td><td>dado 2.1</td><td>dado 3.1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>dado 1.2</td><td>dado 2.2</td><td>dado 3.2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>dado 1.3</td><td>dado 2.3</td><td>dado 3.3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>dado 1.4</td><td>dado 2.4</td><td>dado 3.4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>dado 1.5</td><td>dado 2.5</td><td>dado 3.5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>dado 1.6</td><td>dado 2.6</td><td>dado 3.6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>dado 1.7</td><td>dado 2.7</td><td>dado 3.7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>dado 1.8</td><td>dado 2.8</td><td>dado 3.8</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Não surgiu efeito isso, mas eu acabei encontrando uma outra maneira de resolver o problema, colocando o scroller dentro do tbody e não na janela do navegador, mantendo o thead com `position: sticky;` .